# Tracking online status with Node Js + Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a webpage that uses express Node JS for its real time chat.

I want a green line to be next to users who are online, and red line next to the users who are offline. Each user may have a list of "favourite" users.

My Server Node.JS Code is:

```
var userList = []; //This array will maintain all users online

module.exports = function(app,io){

    // Initialize a new socket.io application, named 'chat'
    var chat = io.on('connection', function (socket) {


        socket.on('join', function (data) {
            socket.join(data.username); 
            var index = userList.indexOf(this.user);
            if (index == -1) {
                userList.push(data.username); //Add User to Array
            }

            this.user = data.username;
            io.sockets.emit('sendusers', { user:  userList } ); //Emit Userlist

        });
        // Remove user from array on disconnect. code not included here
```

On my client side I have:

```
socket.on("sendusers", function (data) {
    loggedInUsers = data;  //Save logged ion users foor use in other areas
    $("#ulusers li").each(function () {
        var currentUser = $(this).find(".first-p").html();
        if ($.inArray(currentUser, data.user) > -1) {
            $(this).css("border-left", "5px solid green");
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("border-left", "5px solid red");
        }
    });
})
```

So basically the logic is: Every time someone joins or leaves the webpage, it emits to everybody the current logged in user list. Then each client iterate through the user list if they are on that page, and sets the css accordingly.

This logic works fine for 10, 100, 500? users. but what happens if the site gets to 1000, 10,000 or more users? How would I maintain the list for each user in this scenario?

Comment: I think that for thousands of user you would use database instead of array to keep track of online users. Also you would only emit to users who have the user which has just joined/left in their list. On the client you would listen for *joined* and *left* messages which would only notify you about ONE user joining or leaving. Well that's my theory :) which basicly means you need to start from scratch if you want to go 10,000

Comment: Thanks for you response. I understand how I can emit join / leave only the 1 user which it corresponds too (i should have thought about that to start with) But my Node JS doesnt know which user has which other user in its favorite list, for that im using a C# MVC. So i'm still going to have to tell every user every single other users join/disconnect status

Comment: So, would the theory go something like, When User leaves, NodeJS queries my SQL DATABASE, finds out which other users have them on their favorite list, then emits to those users only? (its a major redesign :) but i have to do it right )

Comment: Imagine when 10k users is connected and you send them all a message that one user left. Let's say each emit takes 1ms that is 10 seconds for 10k so your server is busy for ten seconds and can't respond to anything else. So yea the theory is you query DB for user's list of other users and emit to them only.